# How come the command works perfectly fine but when I run it, it allows you to guess twice?(Discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

Basically the command runs twice but there's only on version of it
if anyone knows why it runs twice could you explain because this error seems to interest me

````
@bot.command()
async def numguess(ctx):
    primary_id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    number = random.randint(0, 40)
    await ctx.send("I am thinking of a number from 1-40. What is it?")

    for i in range(0, 50):
        response = await ctx.bot.wait_for('message')

        guess = int(response.content)

        if guess > number:
            await ctx.send('That guess is too big! Try again!')

        elif guess < number:
            await ctx.send('That guess is too small! Try again!')

        else:
            await ctx.send(f'You got it right! It only took you {i + 1} attempts! {100 - (i+1)} coins have been earned!')

            amount = 100 - (i + 1)
            amounts[primary_id] += amount

def _save():
    with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(amounts, f)```
````

Comment: You might be running the bot twice in your PC and server.

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: when i run the bot it works but when i do the numguess command it asks me for the number like it should but when i guess it right and it gives me the money.. I can type the same number again without even running the command again and get the money again

Answer (score 0):

I found that if at the end i make it generate a new number yes it will still run twice but the number will be different meaning you can't farm money forever here's the new code

````
@bot.command()
async def numguess(ctx):
    primary_id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    number = random.randint(0, 40)
    await ctx.send("I am thinking of a number from 1-40. What is it?")

    for i in range(0, 50):
        response = await ctx.bot.wait_for('message')

        guess = int(response.content)

        if guess > number:
            await ctx.send('That guess is too big! Try again!')

        elif guess < number:
            await ctx.send('That guess is too small! Try again!')

        else:
            await ctx.send(f'You got it right! It only took you {i + 1} attempts! {100 - (i+1)} coins have been earned!')
            number = random.randint(0, 40)

            amount = 100 - (i + 1)
            amounts[primary_id] += amount
            _save()
def _save():
    with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(amounts, f)```
````